# Calculating interval of time in sessions of users in R

Tags: r

Im really new to Rstudio and i found a code that would help me analyze a dataset.
Could anybody explain a little bit more detailed this line `replace_na(interval(lag(Date), Date)/dminutes(1), 0)` and also the meaning of  `.add = T)` so that i can implement it in my code.

```
session_time_limit <- 30
df <- tibble(ID = c("a", "a", "a", "a", "b", "b", "c", "c", "c"),
             Date = c(as.POSIXct("2021-01-25 19:17:12 UTC"), #a1
                      as.POSIXct("2021-01-25 19:17:30 UTC"), #a2
                      as.POSIXct("2021-01-25 19:57:12 UTC"), #a3
                      as.POSIXct("2021-01-25 19:59:12 UTC"), #a4
                      as.POSIXct("2021-01-25 20:11:12 UTC"), #b1
                      as.POSIXct("2021-01-25 20:42:12 UTC"), #b2
                      as.POSIXct("2021-01-25 21:15:42 UTC"), #c1
                      as.POSIXct("2021-01-25 21:17:12 UTC"), #c2
                      as.POSIXct("2021-01-25 21:20:13 UTC"))) #c3

df %>% 
  group_by(ID) %>%
  mutate(tdiff = replace_na(interval(lag(Date), Date)/dminutes(1), 0),
         session_number = cumsum(tdiff > session_time_limit) + 1) %>% 
  group_by(session_number, .add = T) %>% 
  mutate(activity_within_session = row_number()) %>% 
  ungroup()
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Welcome to SO! It is very easy. But first something important, this code is using functions from `lubridate` (date operations) and `tidyverse` (dataframe processing) packages. So you have to (install if you didnt) and import them:

```
library(lubridate)
library(tidyverse)
```

**1. ¿What `tdiff = replace_na(interval(lag(Date), Date)/dminutes(1), 0)`
does?**

`replace_na(data, replace,...)` just replace the NA values in *data* for the value as *replace* input. So, let`s have a look their inputs:

->   If we call: `interval(lag(Date), Date)/dminutes(1)`, this is the output:

> [1]        NA  0.300000 39.700000  2.000000 12.000000 31.000000 33.500000  1.500000
> [9]  3.01666

So, `replace_na()`is changing the NA value by 0.

> [1]  0.000000  0.300000 39.700000  2.000000 12.000000 31.000000 33.500000  1.500000
> [9]  3.016667

`lag()` funtion is useful when you want to do operations in a row based in another row, so it shift the column *Date* by -1 (the previous one). If you try this:

```
interval(df$Date[1],df$Date[2])/dminutes(1)
```

You will see the output is 0.3 (same as the second row of mutated column *tdiff*). Why do we need `replace_na()`? because if you use lag(), for the first row lag() is shifting to the previous one which doesn't exist, so you get a NA value that you don't want. So you replace by 0.

**2. What  `group_by(session_number, .add = T)` does?**

Here, you are ussing `.add = T` because you already grouped the dataframe by *ID* when you called `>%> group_by(ID)`. If you don't want to lose that grouping you set `.add = T` (as TRUE) to say the *group_by()* function to group the df again based on your previous df grouping. *.add* is set = F by the function so if you don't say that, then you create a new group_by() from the beginning.

Answer (score 1):

This may be something you already know, but a great way to get information on a function is to do ?nameoffunction. So in this case ?interval, ?lag could give you a start. That being said, I know these help sections often confuse me so an extra explanation as you requested makes sense.

`interval` creates an interval as you may expect, so it's a way of specifying two times. For example, using `interval(as.POSIXct("2021-01-25 19:17:12 UTC"), as.POSIXct("2021-01-25 19:17:30 UTC"))`, the first two dates you have, will create the interval `2021-01-25 19:17:12 PST--2021-01-25 19:17:30 PST`. Personally I use intervals to see if a date falls within a certain timeframe. In your code, we also have `lag`, a function which will take the data from the previous row. Thus, if we were on row two, `lag(Date)` would provide the date from row 1, and `Date` would provide the date from row 2, and `interval(lag(Date), Date)` would create the interval I mentioned above.

Then the next part is `dminutes(1)`. This produces a duration object of one minute, or 60 seconds. In this code, we are taking the interval, say between row one and two of 18 seconds, and dividing that by one minute. This produces a 0.3 for the tdiff, meaning 0.3 minutes.

But what if we were on row one? There would be no previous row. In that case the function would see `interval(NA, as.POSIXct("2021-01-25 19:17:30 UTC"))` which would make the interval `NA--NA`. Dividing that by one minute will produce NA. This is where replace_NA could come in handy, anything that is NA would be switched to the specified 0.

Bringing this together, every row of tdiff will give you the number of minutes between itself and the previous row of each group, or 0 if it is the first row or no time elapses presumably.

As for the `.add = T`, I think that might be an error. In `group_by`, `add` is an argument, but not `.add` as far as I'm aware. In help it says `add   When add = FALSE, the default, group_by() will override existing groups. To add to the existing groups, use add = TRUE.` Which I think means if `add = T`, and you make a group within a group, it will have two sets of groups. If you had `add = F`, then the first set of group would be ungrouped, and only the second group would exist. In the given code though, `.add = T` I think might just create an extra column titled .add with all data points listed as `TRUE`.

This is how I understand these functions. Hopefully that helps or points you in the right direction. Best of luck!